# Prevent Chrome Debugger to reload Page when resuming debugger

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

My Webpage contains following items -

- Master page. UpdatePanel. UserControls.  jQuery code.

While debugging, JS in chrome when I continue (F5) I expect the page to load and stay. But actually the page reloads. How do you prevent this situattion ?

Comment: I don't understand why you are using F5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using F5, use F8 to continue.

Answer (score 3):

Un-dock the Chrome Dev Tools Window so it is not embedded within the webpage, then always ensure the dev tools window has the focus before hitting F5. If the webpage window has the focus the F5 command will be interpreted as a refresh.